# Trouble creating DWORD in LocalMachine registry field with C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I am trying to create a DWORD in the LocalMachine registry field using a WinForms (C#) application.

No errors are raised, but the entry is never created.

```
RegistryKey registryKey;
registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration");
registryKey.SetValue("MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB", 512, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Once test in RunAsAdmin and see that created or not ?

Comment: @BehzadKhosravifar see below.  The issue is that it was putting it into the Wow6432Node section for some reason.   When I switched my app be an x64 application the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem before.

With the lasts version of windows you can't write directly to the `LocalMachine` emplacement due to security concern.

They are no error because the key is created in another emplacement. Did you try searching for your key ? Try to execute your program in Admin mode it may create the key.

---

**Edit:**

After some test i found that in **Admin mode** the key is created in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
```

But in **normal user mode** i have the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration' is denied.
```

Comment: Interesting.   By changing my application build configuration to x64 it put it in the correct place.